# How do I save widgets that belong to a page and dynamically render them in the future?

Tags: flutter

So, I need to build custom pages with custom widgets in Flutter, save these pages in memory and recall the custom widgets and their children in the future.

Saving variables is not a problem, as you can use sqlite or json or firebase.

But how can you save an entire page in Flutter??

How can I achieve this?

Please help!

Comment: What you want is pretty unclear. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! So based on user input, the page generates custom widgets i.e, ExpansionPanel widgets. These ExpansionPanel widgets will be arranged in a listview. I need to save this state of the ListView or save the entire Page as a Project file. All the ExpansionPanels with their children (custom widgets) need to be saved for a recall of the entire project in teh future.

Comment: Since you know how to store variables in sqlite, can't you store the variables of your view too?

Comment: You are right! I guess its the only way! I thought perhaps that there another way of doing it. Thanks for the response!

Comment: I think your question is rather strange. Flutter is all about making layout cheap. I wonder why would you need to save entire pages.